Locating a real-valued function in a 2-dimensional matrix
I need help solving the problem of locating a chosen function in a 2-dimensional matrix. Let me explain what I mean precisely. I have two 1-dimensional real grids (arrays) of x(i) and y(j), where i, j = 1, 2, ..., n. For each combination of those grids, I have a real-valued function f(x(i),y(j)) stored in a n x n matrix. Let's now pick a real-valued function g(z,w), assuming that it lies somewhere in the created matrix at the unknown coordinates z and w. Graphically, it will look like this:
  f(x(i),y(j)) - - - f(x(i),y(j+1))
       |                    |
       |       g(z,w)       |
       |                    |
f(x(i+1),y(j)) - - - f(x(i+1),y(j+1))

The question now is, what are the necessary conditions to make sure that the function g(z,w) lies in the presented square? My idea is that the function g should satisfy the following two conditions:

f(x(i),y(j)) < g(z,w) < f(x(i),y(j+1)),
f(x(i),y(j)) < g(z,w) < f(x(i+1),y(j)),

when  f(x(i),y(j)) < f(x(i),y(j+1)) and f(x(i),y(j)) < f(x(i+1),y(j)).
Will the two conditions guarantee that the function g lies in the square? Or do I need more conditions or maybe other conditions? Will the conditions hold if the function f is not ascending (as written after "when" above) except for the sign change?
My other try: If we assume that the function f(x(i),y(j)) is increasing monotonously in each direction, i.e. f(x(i),y(j)) < f(x(i),y(j+1)), f(x(i),y(j)) < f(x(i+1),y(j)) and f(x(i),y(j)) < f(x(i+1),y(j+1)) (or is decreasing monotonously in each direction, i.e. f(x(i),y(j)) > f(x(i),y(j+1)), f(x(i),y(j)) > f(x(i+1),y(j)) and f(x(i),y(j)) > f(x(i+1),y(j+1))) then it should be enough to check that f(x(i),y(j)) < g(z,w) < f(x(i+1),y(j+1)) (or f(x(i),y(j)) > g(z,w) > f(x(i+1),y(j+1)))
